# Gitea: dial tcp: lookup gitea-postgresql.default.svc.cluster.local

Tags: microk8s, gitea

I see this error when trying to use Gitea with microk8s on Ubuntu 21.10:

```
$ k logs gitea-0 -c configure-gitea
Wait for database to become avialable...
gitea-postgresql (10.152.183.227:5432) open
...
2021/11/20 05:49:40 ...om/urfave/cli/app.go:277:Run() [I] PING DATABASE postgres
2021/11/20 05:49:45 cmd/migrate.go:38:runMigrate() [F] Failed to initialize ORM engine: dial tcp: lookup gitea-postgresql.default.svc.cluster.local: Try again
```

I am looking for some clues as to how to debug this please.

The other pods seem to be running as expected:

```
$ k get pod -A
NAMESPACE     NAME                                      READY   STATUS     RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   hostpath-provisioner-5c65fbdb4f-nfx7d     1/1     Running    0          11h
kube-system   calico-node-h8tpk                         1/1     Running    0          11h
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-f7868dd95-dpp8n   1/1     Running    0          11h
kube-system   coredns-7f9c69c78c-cnpkj                  1/1     Running    0          11h
default       gitea-memcached-584956987c-zb8kp          1/1     Running    0          20s
default       gitea-postgresql-0                        1/1     Running    0          20s
default       gitea-0                                   0/1     Init:1/2   1          20s
```

The services are not as expected, since `gitea-0` is not starting:

```
$ k get svc -A
NAMESPACE     NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default       kubernetes                  ClusterIP   10.152.183.1     <none>        443/TCP                  11h
kube-system   kube-dns                    ClusterIP   10.152.183.10    <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   11h
default       gitea-postgresql-headless   ClusterIP   None             <none>        5432/TCP                 3m25s
default       gitea-ssh                   ClusterIP   None             <none>        22/TCP                   3m25s
default       gitea-http                  ClusterIP   None             <none>        3000/TCP                 3m25s
default       gitea-memcached             ClusterIP   10.152.183.15    <none>        11211/TCP                3m25s
default       gitea-postgresql            ClusterIP   10.152.183.227   <none>        5432/TCP                 3m25s
```

Also see:
https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/2741
https://gitea.com/gitea/helm-chart/issues/249

Answer (score 0):

I worked through to the point where I had the logs below, specifically:

```
cmd/migrate.go:38:runMigrate() [F] Failed to initialize ORM engine: dial tcp: lookup gitea-postgresql.default.svc.cluster.local: Try again
```

Using `k cluster-info dump` I saw:

```
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 gitea-postgresql.default.svc.cluster.local.cisco.com. A: read udp 10.1.147.194:56647->8.8.8.8:53: i/o timeout
```

That led me to test the DNS with `dig` and 8.8.8.8. That test didn't reveal any errors, in that DNS seemed to work. Even so, DNS seemed suspect.

So then I tried `microk8s enable storage dns:<IP address of DNS in lab>`, whereas I was previously only `using microk8s storage dns`. The `storage` part enables the persistent volumes that the database needs.

The key piece here is the lab DNS server IP address argument when enabling DNS with microk8s.